# How does gcc/cygwin get the DNS server?

Tags: c, networking, cygwin, dns, libresolv

I have some code I'm writing under cygwin (using GCC) that successfully uses gethostbyname(); however when I try to use the resolver directly to retrieve the IP address of the DNS server it fails (all entries in nsaddr_list[] are null and nscount is -1).
If gethostbyname() is working, then obviously it is able to connect to the DNS server.
This code...

```
    if (res_init() == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"res_init() failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (_res.nscount <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"nscount = %d\n",_res.nscount);
    }
    else {
        for(i=0;i<_res.nscount;i++) {
            fprintf(stderr, "dnssrvr: %d.%d.%d.%d\n",
                (_res.nsaddr_list[i].sin_addr.s_addr & 0xff) >> 0,
                (_res.nsaddr_list[i].sin_addr.s_addr & 0xff00) >> 8,
                (_res.nsaddr_list[i].sin_addr.s_addr & 0xff0000) >> 16,
                (_res.nsaddr_list[i].sin_addr.s_addr & 0xff000000) >> 24);
        }
    }
```

works on unix/linux, but returns nscount=-1 on cygwin.
Is there some trick to getting the DNS server when using cygwin/gcc?

Comment: As an aside, you can use `{ char buf[INET_ADDRSTRLEN]; fprintf(stderr, "dnssrvr: %s\n", inet_ntop(AF_INET, &_res.nsaddr_list[i].sin_addr, buf, sizeof buf)); }` to format the IP address.

Comment: Good point, much cleaner. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [n.m. says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10773280/134633), on Cygwin `res_init()` does not populate `_res.nsaddr_list` if it is using the Windows resolver.  It uses the Windows resolver if either `/etc/resolv.conf` does not exist, or `/etc/resolv.conf` contains `options osquery`.

In my opinion this is a Cygwin bug - returning a negative `nscount` is bogus - but nonetheless we are stuck with working around it.

The solution is to call `GetNetworkParams()` just as Cygwin does itself - here's what I'm doing as a fallback:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

if (_res.nscount < 0)
{
    ULONG buflen = 0;
    FIXED_INFO *buf = NULL;

    if (GetNetworkParams(NULL, &buflen) == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW)
        buf = malloc(buflen);

    if (buf && GetNetworkParams(buf, &buflen) == NO_ERROR)
    {
        _res.nscount = 1;
        _res.nsaddr_list[0].sin_family = AF_INET;
        _res.nsaddr_list[0].sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(buf->DnsServerList.IpAddress.String);
        _res.nsaddr_list[0].sin_port = htons(53);
    }

    free(buf);
}
```

You need to link against `-liphlpapi` for the `GetNetworkParams()` function.

This only takes the first Windows DNS address, but if you want the rest of them you can follow the linked list that `GetNetworkParams()` returns.  `GetNetworkParams()` only returns IPv4 addresses, I'm not sure what you're supposed to do if the machine has an IPv6 DNS server address configured.

Comment: This gives me what I need!  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`res_init` does not necessarily populate `_res.nsaddr_list`. Instead, on Windows it directs the resolver to use `DnsQuery_A`, *unless* you have the `resolv.conf` file, in which case DNS servers from that file are used.

See the source [here](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/src/winsup/cygwin/libc/?cvsroot=src), files `minires.c` and `minires-os-if.c`.

If you need to know your DNS servers, you probably have to use `DnsQueryConfig` or `GetNetworkParams`.

<s>NB: `_res` is undocumented and should not be used.</s>

**UPDATE** <s>Apparently the "newer" (ca 2010 and later) versions of cygwin do populate `_res.nsaddr_list`, via a call to `get_dns_info` and then `get_registry_dns`. You may want to make sure that you have the newest cygwin, and if the problem persists, try to use a debug version and trace calls to the mentioned functions.</s>

**UPDATE 2** No, `_res` is not populated, my mistake.

Comment: Looking closely, even the newest cygwin does not populate the `nsaddr_list` if `use_os` is nonzero - this is true either if there is no `/etc/resolv.conf` or if `/etc/resolv.conf` contains `options osquery`.  So the only way to get cygwin to fill in `nsaddr_list` from the OS list of nameservers is to have an empty `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: @caf: yes. but I think normally there's no `/etc/resolv.conf` on Windows

Comment: Sure - and having *no* `/etc/resolv.conf` causes `nsaddr_list` not to be filled out.  So I think having Cygwin-specific code to call out to `GetNetworkParams()` is looking like the only solution.

Comment: @caf: I think this is incorrect. `res_init` → `res_ninit` → `get_dns_info` (with `use_os==1` and `nscount==0`) → `nscount=-1` → `goto use_registry` and `nsaddr_list` is filled from the registry there.

Comment: @caf: I have no Windows machine right now to check. [This thread](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-patches/2010-q3/msg00028.html) seems to indicate that the sequence outlined in my previous comment doesn't work, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: `get_registry_dns()` only fills out the name servers if `nscount == 0` - otherwise it only retrieves the domain suffix search list.